# I need help trying to understand the concept of Inner Product Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I understand that for something to be called an inner product space, they must be symmetric, bi-linearity and positive definite

But that's about all i know. Can someone explain how to determine if something is symmetric, bi-linearity and positive definite?

Comment: So in other words, you have committed the words in the first sentence to memory but you don’t know what they mean?  Knowing what they mean entails being able to identify them when you see them, or at least being able to get a start doing so.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) has explanations of all the conditions.  If this are insufficient in some way, you should mention how you're specifically confused about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inner product space is a general setting in which you can do Euclidean geometry (possibly in infinite dimensions). It codifies lengths and angles between vectors, indirectly, via a generalisation of the dot product. You get basic geometric theorems, such as Pythagoras's theorem, the angle sum of triangles being $\pi$, and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (i.e. $|u\cdot v| \le \|u\| \|v\|$) but in more general spaces.

In order to properly studies these spaces, the definition of inner product is important. As I mentioned, it generalises the dot product. It takes two vectors $x, y$ and produces a scalar (in this case, real numbers, but more generally, it could be complex!) $\langle x, y \rangle$, like the dot product, and satisfies three axioms:

1. **Positive definiteness**: $\langle x, x \rangle \ge 0$, with $\langle x, x \rangle = 0 \implies x = 0$,
2. **Linearity of the first component**: The map $\langle \cdot, x \rangle$ is a linear map, for all $x$. That is, $\langle \lambda u + v, x \rangle = \lambda \langle u, x \rangle + \langle v, x \rangle$,
3. **Symmetry**: $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle y, x \rangle$.

I'll show this is true of the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, to illustrate how to prove these properties.

For positive definiteness, suppose $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider:
$$(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \cdot (x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 \ge 0,$$
since we are summing square real numbers, all of which are positive. If any $x_i \neq 0$, then $x_i^2 > 0$, which means the sum of squares are strictly positive. Therefore, the only way that the above dot product can be $0$ is if $x_i = 0$ for all $i$, which proves definiteness.

For linearity of the first component, fix $u, v, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
(\lambda u + v) \cdot x &= (\lambda (u_1, \ldots, u_n) + (v_1, \ldots, v_n)) \cdot (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \\
&= (\lambda u_1 + v_1, \ldots, \lambda u_n + v_n) \cdot (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \\
&= (\lambda u_1 + v_1)x_1 + \ldots + (\lambda u_n + v_n)x_n \\
&= \lambda u_1 x_1 + v_1 x_1 + \ldots + \lambda u_n x_n + v_n x_n \\
&= \lambda (u_1 x_1 + \ldots + u_n x_n) + v_1 x_1 + \ldots + v_n x_n \\
&= \lambda (u \cdot x) + v \cdot x.
\end{align*}

Finally, there's symmetry, which is as easy as it seems.

As it turns out, these properties alone can recover much of the useful properties of the dot product that we rely upon.

Recall that $\|x\|$, the length of a vector $x$, can be expressed in terms of the dot product by $\|x\| = \sqrt{x \cdot x}$. In a general inner product space, we define the "norm" on the space to be $\|x\| := \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$.

We can talk about vectors being orthogonal. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, vectors $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal if and only if their dot product is $0$. Correspondingly, we say $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal (defining the term) in an inner product space if $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$.

In terms of proving inner products, be prepared for positive definiteness to be the hardest to prove!

Comment: It's late for me so i'll just give you the best answer for now. Tomorrow i will consider asking you questions about things that i don't fully understand about your post. Thank you.

Comment: ok thank you i finally understand.